# Link for an earned badge in the iOS app

Tags: bug, badges, ios-app

Recently I've earned a badge for an answer. If I tap on notification in web:

> [image: web]

It refers me to the [answer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/544621) (try this in web and in the app):

> [image: answer]

But if I do the same in the app, question will be opened instead:

> [image: ios]

- App Version: 1.6.3.4
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)